# How can I get an accurate representation of a function/lambda?

Tags: python, function, lambda

I've been attempting to learn python lately, and I decided I'd like a string representation of a lambda. I tried doing what seemed obvious at the time:

```
quux = lambda x: 1-abs(x)
print(quux) #<function <lambda> at 0xfacefedaf>
```

This was almost as helpful as JavaScript's `function foo(){ <native code> }`.

What I was really hoping for was something that showed what the function actually did, such as:

```
<function <lambda>: x:1-abs(x)>
```

or simply the original

```
x:1-abs(x)
```

Python doesn't seem to have any `uneval` function, and I'm not really sure where to look through the various lifesaving modules for something like it.

Other stuff I tried:

```
print(repr(quux))
print(str(quux))
```

Comment: As an aside `quux = lambda x: 1-abs(x)` is bad form. You shouldn't use `lambda` for named functions. The **only** good use-case for `lambda` is for anonymous functions.

Comment: Ugh, my love of JavaScript's arrow functions comes to bite me in the back. Thanks for the advice, I use way too many bad practices.